# How to automatically document Metaprogrammed attr_accessors using RDoc?

Tags: ruby, rdoc

FIRST, I would like to customize RDoc such that it automatically recognizes each key of the `attrs` hash `foo` and `bar` of the following code:

```
class SomeClass
  def initialize( args = { }) 
    attrs = { 'foo'  => nil,
              'bar'    => 'us'}
    attrs.each_key{ |key| (class << self; self; end).send( :attr_accessor, key.to_sym)}

    attrs.each_key do |key|
      attrs[ key] = args[ key] if( args.has_key?( key))
      raise "No #{key} defined" if( attrs[key] === nil))
    end

    attrs.each {|key, value| instance_variable_set( "@#{key}", value)}
  end
end
```

As if I had initialized them as follows:

```
class SomeClass
  attr_accessor :foo, :bar
  def initialize( foo = nil, bar = 'us') 
      raise "No foo defined" if( foo === nil))
      @foo = foo
      @bar = bar
  end
end
```

I am able to do the following and have the accessors show up properly as `Attributes`:

```
class SomeClass
  ##
  # :attr_accessor: foo

  ##
  # :attr_accessor: bar

  ##
  # this is a comment for a the initialize method

  def initialize( args = { }) 
    attrs = { 'foo'  => nil,
              'bar'    => 'us'}
    attrs.each_key{ |key| (class << self; self; end).send( :attr_accessor, key.to_sym)}

    attrs.each_key do |key|
      attrs[ key] = args[ key] if( args.has_key?( key))
      raise "No #{key} defined" if( attrs[key] === nil))
    end

    attrs.each {|key, value| instance_variable_set( "@#{key}", value)}
  end
end
```

But I would like to be able to have RDoc recognize these automatically!

SECOND, I would like to be able to make comment relevant to their definitions in a manor similar to the following and have the comments show up in the documentation:

```
class SomeClass
  def initialize( args = { }) 
    attrs = { 
              ##
              #This stores your Foo
              'foo'  => nil,
              ##
              #This stores your Bar
              'bar'    => 'us'}
    attrs.each_key{ |key| (class << self; self; end).send( :attr_accessor, key.to_sym)}

    attrs.each_key do |key|
      attrs[ key] = args[ key] if( args.has_key?( key))
      raise "No #{key} defined" if( attrs[key] === nil))
    end

    attrs.each {|key, value| instance_variable_set( "@#{key}", value)}
  end
end
```

LAST, I would like their default values automatically listed as well (i.e. within the documentation it would list with the attributes that by default `foo = nil` and `bar = 'us'`).

I have been examining the RDoc documentation for the Ruby code parser [RDoc::Parser::Ruby](http://rdoc.rubyforge.org/RDoc/Parser/Ruby.html) and I would like to build a plugin as described in the [RDoc Developer Introduction](http://rdoc.rubyforge.org/DEVELOPERS_rdoc.html) but I am unsure of how to even begin.

1) Is there something out there which already accomplishes what I have described?
2) If nothing exists, could someone please point me to an example plugin accomplishing similar functionality?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this. Maybe instead of trying `self.send(...)` you _might_ be able to use `attr_*(key)`, if RDoc is smart enough for that.

Comment: The code functions exactly as I want it to, what I need is dynamically generated documentation.  I'm looking for a way to configure RDoc such that it recognizes each of my attr_*s objects in my initialize method (i.e. `attr_writers` `attr_readers` `attr_accessors`) and simply puts them into my documentation noting their default values.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think RDoc has those capabilities. But it probably wouldn't be too hard to build one on top of it yourself.

Comment: [yard](http://yardoc.org) can do that.

Comment: @whitequark How?? I've been reading through `YARD` content for a few hours but I'm unable to identify exactly how to go about doing this?  Could you point me to an example doing something similar?

Comment: @KurtRudolph, wait, you want RDoc to parse some hash in your code for you and extract method names from it? That's impossible. Doing this would require just running your code, which a documentation tool shouldn't and won't do.

Comment: On the other hand, you can make some DSL to do the same task and then use [YARD macros](http://rubydoc.info/docs/yard/file/docs/Tags.md#Macros) to attach documentation to these definitions. What you are doing is pretty dirty anyway and would be much better done with a DSL.

Comment: @whitequark Why is what I am doing dirty?  My ultimate goal is to be able to define `attr_*`s without having to write anything twice, documentation included.  How would I accomplish this in a DSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a Domain Specific Language (DSL) and use [Yard Macro Expansion Variables](http://rubydoc.info/docs/yard/file/docs/Tags.md#macro).

Also see my other related questions:

- [Iterating over the registers of a Yardoc `@macro`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343634/iterating-over-the-registers-of-a-yardoc-macro)
- [How to make Yard `@macro`s apply to multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324926/how-to-make-yard-macros-apply-to-multiple-files)
- [Dynamic documentation, using the return of method in the description of another YARD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321789/dynamic-documentation-using-the-return-of-method-in-the-description-of-another)
- [Ruby DSLs and Dynamic Documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396213/ruby-dsls-and-dynamic-documentation)