# Iterating over the registers of a Yardoc `@macro`

Tags: ruby, documentation, yard

I am looking for way to iterate over the registers of a yardoc `@macro`. I know you are able to use them in something like as follows:

```
class Post
  include DataMapper::Resource

  # @macro dm.property
  # @return [$2] the $1 $0 of the post
  property :title, String
end
```

and you are able generate the arguments the registers represent separated by comas as if you were taking a section of an array like as follows:

```
# @macro dsl_method
# @method $1(${2--2})
# @return [${-1}] the return value of $0
create_method_with_args :foo, :a, :b, :c, String
```

generates: `foo(a, b, c)` and `returns (String) the return value of create_method_with_args` but I am interested in call something like `(${2--1}).each do |$arg|` and do documentation say each of the params with a single line of documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately macros are an extremely simplistic tool to reduce DRYness of docs. We opted out of implementing executable macros due to security concerns (you probably don't want Ruby running in your comments). They aren't really a one-size-fits-all solution to all problems, but they work well in the very simple cases. Plugins are still the recommended way to go for the more complicated cases.

That said, since you would still have to specify the actual parameter documentation *somewhere*, I don't see how even a plugin would simplify anything for you. If I were you, I would simply define it as you already have, and use `@param` tags to define each of the arguments separately. For example (let's assume the macro was previously "attached" the way you did in your question):

```
# @param [String] a documentation for a
# @param [Symbol] b documentation for b
# @param [Hash] c documentation for c
create_method_with_args :bar, :a, :b, :c, Fixnum
```

That seems pretty reasonable to me, since there's not much else you can DRY up in those docs.

**Edit**: see comments for cases where may also want to use [custom handlers](https://yardoc.org/guides/extending-yard/writing-handlers.html) or the newer [directives](https://rubydoc.info/gems/yard/0.9.22/YARD/Tags/Directive) if your needs extend beyond the limitations of macros and you are fine with using custom YARD extensions or plugins.

Comment: But then how do you approach a DSL with a dynamic number of arguments being created for the method such as in the example I made [here](https://gist.github.com/2510343).  Ultimately I would like to define the DSL in the spirit of this statement `def self.property( name, type, (arg_name, default, type, required)*)`.  Coming from a heavy C background I guess the best way I am able describe it is I would like to input a dynamic number of something equivalent to a struct and have each dynamically documented documented as an `@param` accordingly to values contained within the struct.

Comment: This also doesn't work for documenting DSL methods that take more than one argument and then operate on each argument e.g. to define attributes or methods.

Comment: @BM5k this is a very old thread FYI. YARD now has [Directives](https://rubydoc.info/gems/yard/0.9.22/YARD/Tags/Directive) which basically allow you to process code however you like in the cases where more complex logic is required. Macros were never meant to be a Turing Complete style templating system.

Comment: Interesting, so it's theoretically possible to build a directive that would make documenting this kind of dsl possible.

Comment: @BM5k sure, but if using custom code is acceptable, the better solution would be to [implement a custom handler](https://yardoc.org/guides/extending-yard/writing-handlers.html) which has been supported far longer than directives and requires no custom user comment markup.

Comment: Thanks, I will def be taking a look at this.

Comment: I can't un-downvote your answer unless it is edited. Even though this Q&A is super old, would you be willing to edit the answer to include the two links you shared?